# How to create a BigBlueButton user from another app (straight to Redis?)

Tags: redis, bigbluebutton

We're building an e-school where we want to create a BigBlueButton user with different rights depending on if a student or teacher signs up.

Can't find an API call nor webhook to create a user so wondering if it's maybe possible to create straight to the DB the user? Redis is used for DB? Or what's the best way to do so.

Also, need to save in our e-school database then the user ID in our `users` table `bbb_user` field to be able to assign rooms and meetings to that user via API.

Comment: Someone suggested: Actually, you don’t need to sign up users to the BBB, moderator when creating the call will generate a password that will be sent to the users that will attend the meeting. So you just assign in your own database (not in BBB Redis) rooms to your users and meetings to the rooms.

Comment: But then not sure if it's really that you just come up with userID from your database and don't need to pre-register that user beforehand in BBB?

Answer (score 1):

If you have created the meeting, then you can call APIs like this:

join as moderator (teacher)

```
https://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/api/join?fullName=User+5209488&meetingID=random-6182117&password=mp&redirect=true&checksum=f68e963ade89ace13b6a15648289b400dd31a36b
```

join as attendee (student)

```
https://test-install.blindsidenetworks.com/bigbluebutton/api/join?fullName=User+5209488&meetingID=random-6182117&password=ap&redirect=true&checksum=2f68c7e33c4427526807bef3cc2a0ee4ec7c2d62
```

for more details about API requests, take a look at [api-mate](https://mconf.github.io/api-mate/)

Comment: That's clear yes but we want to implement a custom design to it: https://projects.crewnew.com/schoolify/schoolify-fe-develop/public/video/video.html Maybe this can be used: https://docs.bigbluebutton.org/legacy/html5-overview.html Can you help with implementing this custom design to BBB. If you want us to hire you please add Skype: kasparpalgi